# Ubuntu and www:data permissions in amazon aws

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I have a Joomla website hosted at amazon aws and having issues with permissions.

Every time I have to go to terminal, ssh and do this to change the permissions between Joomla (www-data) and FileZilla (ubuntu)

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html (Joomla)
sudo chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html (File Zilla)
```

How do I set it so that I don't have to change this every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the ubuntu user to the www-data group

```
# usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

then

```
# chmod g+w /var/www/html -R
```

(group writeable) all your files.

Comment: it's simple but I've seen most answers warn not to give write permission to www-data as it's a security risk

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to get this to work for a while and tried adding the ubuntu user to data group but still couldn't get this to work. Finally! after hours of searching file permissions is somewhat secure with me actually being able to upload files via SFTP with permissions and still not having write access on all folders. Perfect!